# Ignoring feature with featureIdentified with Pyqgis

Tags: pyqgis

I am using the QgsMapToolEmitPoint and QgsMapToolIdentifyFeature classes in my QGIS project.

I created 2 variables:

```
self.pointTool = QgsMapToolEmitPoint (self.canvas)
self.linetool = QgsMapToolIdentifyFeature (self.canvas)
```

The first variable connects to a function that generates lines in a layer.
Next, I call the second function, which identifies the end point of the lines where I click.

My problem is, after making a line, calling the second function:

```
self.pointTool.canvasClicked.connect (self.criar_line)
self.linetool.featureIdentified.connect (self.identify)
```

this function captures the end point of the line
created earlier, but I don't want that.
I want to choose the line I want to capture the endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are catching the feature object which is passed by the `featureIdentified` signal, and using it when you define your `self.identify` slot function like this:

```
def identify(self, feat):
    geom = feat.geometry().constGet()[0]
    end_point = QgsPointXY(geom[-1])
    X = end_point.x()
    Y = end_point.y()
    # do something with end_point, X, or Y
```

Also, make sure your identify tool has the correct layer set to it, either by passing the layer object to the class constructor:

```
self.linetool = QgsMapToolIdentifyFeature(self.canvas, self.layer)
```

or by using the `setLayer()` method:

```
self.linetool.setLayer(self.layer)
```

Where `self.layer` is the `QgsVectorLayer` object of your line layer.